# Need help disconnecting Kohler collet connection

Tags: plumbing, collet

[image]
I'm trying to replace my Kohler faucet with a Delta Leland with Shieldspray. But I can't remove this connection. I took advice from a video to first move it up out of the sink (below there is no leverage), but can't remove it still. I'm told to push the white ring away from the hose into the metal, then twist the hose out, but that doesn't work. I've tried twisting in both directions with WD40.

Comment: wrong direction. Push the white ring do not pull it.